# Understanding how Spring Security works with role sortorder

Tags: grails, spring-security

If sortorder is used correctly with SpringSecurity, how do the `SpringSecurityUtil` methods behave? For example, `ifAnyGranted` seems to check if the user has any role with a lower sortorder than roles passed.

Given the following:

```
ROLE_EXEC     sortorder:10
ROLE_MANAGER  sortroder:20
ROLE_EMPLOYEE sortorder:30

//does this mean "has any role with at least the same sortorder as someRole"?
SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted("ROLE_MANAGER") //would return true for manager or exec?

//does this mean "does not have any role with at least the sortorder of someRole"
SpringSecurityUtils.ifNotGranted("ROLE_EXEC") //would return true for manager or employee?

//does this mean "all roles equal or above all of these"?

SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted("ROLE_MANAGER") // returns true for manager or exec? ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where `sortorder` is from but there's no support in the plugin for what you're describing.

You can easily define a role hierarchy though, which should hopefully do what you're looking for. It's typically used to make `@Secured` annotations less verbose, e.g. defining that ROLE_ADMIN implies ROLE_USER, so you can allow admins and users with `@Secured('ROLE_USER')` instead of `@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')`.

See the documentation [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#hierarchicalRoles).